# Algebraic integer modulo p

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

How can I calculate algebraic integer ( primitive roots of unitary for example) mod p ?

I need them in modular representation of finite groups.

More explanation :

https://books.google.com.sa/books?id=lyqAvBzeBSAC&lpg=PP1&dq=character%20of%20block%20theory&hl=ar&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q=character%20of%20block%20theory&f=false

In page 16

I want to find the image of primitive roots of unitary under the natural map.

Comment: Huh, I've never tried doing modular arithmetic with complex numbers.

Comment: Look to more explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate"? Isn't it enough to know that there's an element, call it $\alpha$, in the field of $p$ elements (or in some finite extension of that field) that acts as a primitive $n$th root of unity?

Comment: @SimpleArt you should look at why $\mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{R}[x] / (x^2+1)$, representing $a+ib$ as the polynomial $a+xb$ in $\mathbb{R}[x] / (x^2+1)$

Comment: And so you didn't mean a primitive root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an algebraic number field $K$ there is a concept of algebraic integers of that field usually denoted $\mathcal {O}_K$: this consists of those elements of $K$ satisfying *monic* equations with integer coefficients.

There is no unique factorization available for the elements of these rings: instead we have a unique factorization of the *ideals* as product of non-zero prime ideals (they are also maximal ideals).

Now coming to your question given a prime number $p$ the principal ideal generated by it in $\mathcal {O}_K$ need not be a prime ideal; so we factorize this ideal in $\mathcal {O}_K$: the prime ideals occurring in the factorization are precisely those containing the element $p$.

One can talk of quotient rings $\mathcal {O}_K$ modulo  such prime ideals $P$. This is the analogue of mod $p$ operation you are looking for.  The restriction of the canonical map $\mathcal {O}_K\to \mathcal {O}_K/P$ to $\mathbf{Z}$ will provide an embedding of the finite field  of $p$ elements.

$\mathcal {O}_K/P$ is also a finite field and its degree over its prime subfield is called  the inertial degree of the prime ideal $P$ over $p$. As there are many prime ideals this depends on the choice of $P$. However for Galois extension $K$ over over  rationals these inertial degrees are the same. You can read these things in the book *Number Fields* by Marcus, for example.